# Swing forward and back animation jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

Guys what's wrong with this code ?

```
var func = function() {
    $("#ropes").animate({"left": "-40px"}, 1000, function() { 
        $(this).animate({"left": "40px"}, 1000) 
    })

    setTimeout(func, 2000);
}
```

Comment: why don't you tell us? we don't know what you want to do with that code, or, if it's not working, we don't know what's not working because we don't know what's the work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link and it'll show you what should be happening. Basically it just looks like you've not started the function off. Hopefully it'll help a little to sorting your problem though.

http://jsfiddle.net/9n2h8/

Comment: I agree and would farther more suggest not to use setTimeout as to not be dependent on the animation speed. Here's an alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/9n2h8/1/

Comment: Yeah like iMoses has said don't use setTimeout if it can be helped within animation. Although you are setting the times for these animations to run it's all down to chance that they all kick off at the same time.